# Django: Strategies for tracking and displaying users data

Tags: python, django, authentication

## Details

I have made my custom authentication process for the users, (no, i didn't use django's dedicated authentication), I almost finished it, but still having concerns on the most important part at the time.

so these are main parts of authentication process:

1. User sign's into the website via steam's social authentication.
2. My authentication system checks if database contains user's data, if not it will create a new user object with all the information.
3. System will create cookie as key `logged` with the value of True.

After these steps, there begins a problem, website should show users data when `logged` cookie's value is True.

## Strategies and Questions

So as example, let's take stackoverflow, as i see: when it's login cookie is activated, it show's me my profile picture, and my score.

How did it know that i was that specific user?

**via cookies**:

If i tracked users data via cookies, i know that it would be a very bad idea since they are super-easy to change.

**via ip address**:

Then there's a second way, to track them with ip address, which i don't think is a good idea:

```
from .models import User, IPs

from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse

import steamapi

def index(request, self):
    ip = request.META['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] 
    for search in IPs.objects.all():
        if str(ip) in str(search):
            break
            user = ip.strip(ip) # model will contain ip address with username. e.g ( user 127.0.0.1 ), so i strip the ip
        else:
            username = steamapi.user.SteamUser(self.steamid) # i get steamid from different function which is not important.
            username = IPs(data=username + " " + ip)
            username.save()
    print request.COOKIES
    if request.COOKIES.get('logged'):
        return HttpResponse("User %s" + "is logged in" % username)
    else:
        response = HttpResponse("User is not logged in")
        response.set_cookie('logged', True)
        return response
```

**via sessions**:

I don't exactly know Django's sessions (except cookies), would it be good if i used django's cached sessions? if so how?

**Note**: i am looking for the code that will fit to my steps at beginning, so code example would be excellent.

---

First strategy is totally bad idea, i think second is not pythonic and is not a good strategy, Third however, is one i need a help with.

## General Question:

So what would best strategy be for displaying specific users data on the website? As i mentioned simillar to stackoverflow's bar, where it displays my profile picture and score.

Answer (score 2):

Writing your own auth system is a nice way to learn all the details of how it works, but you must be careful to not introduce security issues. The Django auth framework has been working for 10 years or so, so it can be trusted to do the right thing.

Bruno's answer is right: you should use sessions. Sessions work by setting a cookie with a random  value on the user's computer. After that, the browser sends back that random value on each request, and the Django Session framework (a middleware, IIRC) matches the random string with a Session instance (dict like object) and puts it in the request instance.

If you're using a modern Django version and for any reason want to stick to using Cookies only, you can check out the new [Cookie based sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/sessions/#using-cookie-based-sessions). Internally, it signs the cookie (meaning no-one else can tamper with it, even though it's stored on the user's computer).

Comment: so for example, if i set cookie like this: `response.set_cookie('username', 'something')`, user could not be able to change it? i did not know that security for the system would be such difficult.

Comment: @ShellRox DONT set the username in a cookie for God's sake ! And no, that's NOT how you use django's cookie-based sessions (please follow the link in the answer). And yes, security IS a very complex topic and very hard to get right, so better to stick with something that is known to work. As Tiago says, `contrib.auth` has been maintained and enhanced for ten+ years now by a lot of seasoned programmers, and is part of what makes Django one of the most secure web frameworks. Yes the code is "more complicated" than your own but you're probably starting to find out why...

Answer (score 1):

The canonical solution is to use [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/sessions/).  FWIW note that all of your problems are already solved in Django's `contrib.auth` app, taking care of a whole lot of known security issues.

Comment: Which would be the best type of sessions for this concern? would cached sessions do a work?

Comment: The simplest is to use the db backend, but any backend will do - they are just backends, really.

Comment: that would be a good idea, but i still don't know how what could should i exactly write in to fill my needs, could i see example of main parts ?

Comment: @ShellRox I already suggested that you _at least_ read `contrib.auth` code - if will show you how it's done. Actually you'd better just *use* it instead of insisting on reinventing the proverbial squared wheel...

Comment: My bad for misunderstanding, I think `get_user` function was the part that i needed. My code is way simpler than this one, i'm just trying to find the code that will fit mine as in the steps.

Comment: Your code is simpler now, but once you'll be finished with it, it will be _much_ more complicated, and certainly not as secure and well tested as `contrib.auth`. If you want a pythonic solution: use what's already implemented, is known to work and is considered as de-facto standard instead of insisting on rolling your own solution. __The problems you're trying to solve have already been solved__, and well solved.

Comment: It is understandable, but i do not know how to use Django's authentication system for my needs, For example customizing User model inside since i do not need an email field.

Comment: If you don't need the email field, just leave it blank. If you need extra fields, there's a way to do that in django, you don't have to reinvent the wheel (unless you're doing with the purpose of learning, then do reinvent it and have fun, but beware of using in production).